# Putting multiple ButtonGroups in one JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I'm trying to put multiple JButtons on a frame, using ButtonGroup.

I have to put 3 groups of buttons on a frame, seperated form each other.

The following code does create the buttons, but instead of being seperated, they seem to be "deleting" each other.

**I'm expecting to see there seperate groups of buttons, 4 buttons each.**

The method accepts an ArrayList of a "Question" Objects, which looks like that:

```
public class Question {
private String _question;
private String _option1;
private String _option2;
private String _option3;
private String _option4;
}
```

Here's the method. It's inside a class which **inherits a frame** from another class, "DisplayOnPanel" to set the Panels on the same frame. "this" refers to a frame:

```
public void addButtonstoFrame(ArrayList<Question> q){
    ArrayList<ButtonGroup> BG = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<JPanel> JP = new ArrayList<>();

    JLabel question1 = new JLabel();
    int j=0;
    for (int i = 0; i <q.size() ; i++) {
        BG.add(new ButtonGroup());
        JP.add(new JPanel());
        JRadioButton option1 = new JRadioButton(q.get(i).get_option1());
        JRadioButton option2 = new JRadioButton(q.get(i).get_option2());
        JRadioButton option3 = new JRadioButton(q.get(i).get_option3());
        JRadioButton option4 = new JRadioButton(q.get(i).get_option4());
        BG.get(j).add(option1);
        BG.get(j).add(option2);
        BG.get(j).add(option3);
        BG.get(j).add(option4);
        JP.get(j).add(option1);
        JP.get(j).add(option2);
        JP.get(j).add(option3);
        JP.get(j).add(option4);


        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); //this referes to a frame
        this.add(JP.get(j)); //this referes to a frame
        JP.get(i).setLocation(j+10,j+10);
        JP.get(j).setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(true);//this referes to a frame
        j++;
    }

}
```

And the result is just 4 butoons, instead of 12:

[image: result]

Thank you!

Comment: Please always include a complete code sample (SSCCE).

Comment: It's a lot of code actually, and I was told the last time not to post my whole code :-(

Comment: You're not being told to post your whole code now. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Tip for @Amber: `[mcve]` auto-expands in a comment to [mcve].

Comment: I guess they keyword is "short".  You shouldn't post your whole code, but you should post a minimal complete sample that shows the problem.  i.e. A class with a main method.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a BorderLayout? I think that's what's throwing you off.

Comment: Thank you! I changed to "Flow Layout" and I got 3 groups of buttons!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

```
    JRadioButton option1 = new JRadioButton(q.get(i).get_option1());
    JRadioButton option2 = new JRadioButton(q.get(i).get_option2());
    JRadioButton option3 = new JRadioButton(q.get(i).get_option3());
    JRadioButton option4 = new JRadioButton(q.get(i).get_option4());
    BG.get(j).add(option1);
    BG.get(j).add(option2);
    BG.get(j).add(option3);
    BG.get(j).add(option4);
    JP.get(j).add(option1);
    JP.get(j).add(option2);
    JP.get(j).add(option3);
    JP.get(j).add(option4);
```

A component can only belong to a single parent container.

When you add the button to the "JP" contain, you remove it from the "BG" container.

So you need to create 4 more instances of each radio button.

Comment: I see. So can is there a way I create the radio buttons once? Maybe I'm creating too many JPs?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can't share components on different panels and you can't add the same component twice to the same panel. You need to create multiple  instances of  the component. If you have an "apple" at home. You can't put the apple in the fridge and on a basket on your kitchen table. You need two apples.

Comment: My question is how do I make it possible for each 4 buttons to be on the same group, without having to write 8 lines of code for that. Thank you!

Comment: You can always create a method that creates a panel and then adds 4 buttons to the panel. Then you invoke the method twice. This is basic programming. If you want to repeat the same block of code you make a method. Or you can create a loop. Inside the loop you create the buttons and panel and invoke the loop twice.

Comment: Thank you. So I understand that whatever I do I have to call twice a block of code which creates the buttons.

Comment: @camickr, I don't think this is the problem.  There is nothing wrong with adding a radio button to a JPanel and to a ButtonGroup.

Comment: @Amber `There is nothing wrong with adding a radio button to a JPanel and to a ButtonGroup.` - thanks. I wasn't playing close enough attention to the variables names. I guess that's what happens when people don't use "descriptive" names